# asp.net-mvc: Adding a passwordFor to the view auto populates my fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, passwords, auto-populate

The scenario: I am trying to add a view to Create new users by admin. The app is form authentication. There is a logged in user(admin). When a Password For is added to the view, the view automatically populates the fields with the logged in user.

The controller code:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var userViewModel = new UserViewModel();
    return View(userViewModel);
}
```

The view code:

```
@model MVC4.Models.UserViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>UserVireModelcs</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Does it happen if you don't send a model to the view?  It seems kind of strange to send an empty model anyway.

Comment: Yes, that is why I tried sending an empty one, but it happens ether way.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the browser pre-filling the login form?  "Username" and "Password" fields would likely be interpreted by the browser as a login prompt.

Comment: You are right! I tested on a different browser and It didn't. How will I make it not happened?

Comment: In that case you'd either clear the login information from the browser, or perhaps rename the fields on the page (and use a different view model) so that the browser doesn't think it's a login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I *suspect* is happening here is that the *application* isn't pre-filling the fields, but the *browser* is.  This is because this form looks *exactly* like a login prompt.  (You can test this by clearing your information from the browser itself so that it doesn't auto-fill any login prompt on this site.)

What I would recommend is to semantically separate the concepts of logging in and creating a user.  Basically... rename the fields.  A simple view model with some more specific names would help:

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
    public string NewUserUsername { get; set; }
    public string NewUserPasswords { get; set; }
}
```

Then use that in your view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model. NewUserUsername)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model. NewUserUsername)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model. NewUserUsername)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewUserPassword)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.NewUserPassword)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewUserPassword)
</div>
```

It's a little more verbose than perhaps one might want it to be (I would agree that simpler is always better), but adding some explicit context to the naming in this case makes it more clear to the browser that this *isn't* a login form.  Use any naming that makes sense for your needs, just make it more descriptive than `Username` and `Password`.